# Get service name,Port# and IP address of oracle 10g host

Tags: unix, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to connect to Oracle 10g using sql developer. Currently i am able to connect using sql plus command from command line

```
sqlplus username/pwd@dbname
```

I need to find IP address/hostname, port#, servicename/sid from the current connection in sql plus.

Found all information required other than port # using gv$session. In oracle 11 i found that port number can be found from gv$session. But not in 10g. Any other ways to figure it out?

Anyways to figure out how to connect using sql developer? 
Or atleast to know if i am even allowed to connect from remote to this server?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the port number from `listener.ora`

Locate the following section of the file:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

Location of `listener.ora`

Linux : `/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/network/admin/`

Windows: `c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\NETWORK\ADMIN\`

Comment: I am facing permission issues with the oracle directory to open these direcotries. Any other options . Like an sql query?

Comment: @user1016198 .. then you must check with your AD or DBA. I am not sure  if you can get this using query.